# Unchecked checkboxes and hidden input problem

Tags: php, html, forms, post, checkbox

We have an edit form:we populate it with a variable number of checkboxes (it all depends,let's say, on how many pictures we have on the article we're about to edit).
**All the checkboxes are per default "checked"** and if nothing happens the data associated(our pictures in this case) remains untouched.
Altough if we uncheck one we actually want to not keep the picture in our edited post and delete it from our database.

I know unchecked checkboxes dont get Posted,and that I have one work-around:
place right before the checkbox an hidden field with the same name..in this way with the checkbox unchecked can still post the hidden input.
but i have this situation:

```
/*i'm querying the database to load all the article's data and I check if  */
/* there's any picture so I build, with a while loop, an associated checkbox*/
 <input type="checkbox" name="picture[]" value="$row['pic_id]"/>$row['pic_name']
```

When I submit our edit form I check if there's any data inside our **array picture** and if positive i want to delete it from database.
Now if I simply add an hidden field at the top of each checkbox (so same name and same value..cause it's the value i need to use in the next query) I fall into the problem:
**how to distinguish if the posted data comes from the actual checkbox (if eventually checked) or from the hidden input??**

thanks again
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server side you can use the following approach:

```
$array_of_ids_to_delete=array_diff($array_with_all_ids, $posted_ids);
```

The `$array_with_all_ids` must be already available, because I guess you use it to output all the checkboxes. `$posted_ids` represents your picture[] array.

After that you only have to run a `foreach` on `$array_of_ids_to_delete` and get rid of those images.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you check it on the server side?

You know what was the original list, you have your new list. Those that are not in the new list, but were in the original list, should be deleted.

So you don't need to add any javascript hacks, or hidden inputs.

Comment: and how i can build this comparison between the two list?how can i see if something is missing in the new list?

Comment: I don't know PHP, so I cannot give you a code sample. But basically you loop through your old list, and check for each value if exists in the new list. Does PHP has a Contains() function. If not you use an inner loop on the new list, checking if value from old list == value in new list. If it equals, you continue to the next value in your old list. If it reaches the end of the loop, it means it doesn't exist anymore , and you'll perform a delete.

Comment: Just saw PHP has an in_array function, you can use that in your loop (of your original list). If the new list contains the old value: OK, if not DELETE.

Comment: Good luck. If it doesn't work out, post a question about loops in PHP etc. So that PHP people will be able to help you out there. This is the cleanest solution.